Gui for Developers to start azure VMs on-demand
Im trying to implement a GUI that is simple that lists all Azure vms within a subscription and enables our Dev team to Start it..I would like for the VM to automatically stop(deallocate) after 8 hours.
I've found a solution on github that is almost exactly what I'm looking for except that it requires a schedule vs being on-demand. https://github.com/sg3-141-592/AzStartStop
I've forked this and i'm trying to edit the Python code but I'm in over my head. If I had clear direction on what to edit, I could do it but not without someone showing me the way.
I'm assuming that the Function_Schedule.py is what I edit however, I'm not sure how to edit the menu option on the function app site.
app folder
